# Remote-SSH: How to enable and use an extension in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am following this tutorial:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh-tutorial

I have the extension installed..

[image]

And I can see the green button

[image]

But when I look for the Remote-SSH command in the search bar that pops up, I cannot find it

[image]

Am I missing a step?

This is my vs code version info

Version: 1.67.2 (Universal)
Commit: c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5
Date: 2022-05-17T18:20:57.384Z (4 mos ago)
Electron: 17.4.1
Chromium: 98.0.4758.141
Node.js: 16.13.0
V8: 9.8.177.13-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.6.0

Comment: click the green button in the bottom left

Answer (score 0):

For some reason command+shift+p brings up the menu with > Remote Connection shown, but the green button does not. Not sure what the difference is.